# Maple: Symmetries of strange modified heat-equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, symmetry, maple, heat-equation

I thought about the following PDE (**the $u(x=0,t)$ is not a boundary condition! It really is a part of the PDE)**:

$$\dfrac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}=\alpha \dfrac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+u(x=0,t).$$

How can i determine the symmetries of this PDE with Maple? And how are such PDEs called?

Comment: It is a bit weird looking, the inhomogeneous term introduces a non-local effect. Without knowing the specific terminology, searching for 'non-local heat equation' might begin to get you somewhere.

Comment: What is the domain of $x$ and is $x = 0$ a boundary point? i.e. is the value of $u(0,t)$ specified in the problem?

Comment: No its not given. and it is not a boundary value

Comment: That is very strange, I just thought it might have been a heat equation being forced with the boundary condition at $x = 0$ and the author had just tried to be *clever* and write it as such.

Comment: @okrzysik I just came up with such an PDE. I found it factinating as i never saw such a PDE.

Comment: This can be though of as the PDE $u_t = \alpha u_{xx} + f(t)$ with the boundary condition $u(0,t) = f(t)$. There are probably infinitely many solutions - one for every (viable) choice of $f$.

Comment: @Winther No this is not a boundary condition. It is just the function at a specific value.

Comment: If you solve the equation I presented with the given boundary condition then that solution is also a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Winther: Ah i get it. Is this the way one approaches such PDEs in general? Have you any resource that explain these types of problems in further detail?

Comment: Such PDEs usually don't come up at all. I can't say for sure but atleast I have never seen a PDE written on that form before (but my experience is limited to PDEs in physics) so I can't help you with a reference.